# ¿Como ver el nombre de la BBDD con nodejs y javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Estoy aprendiendo a usar `nodeJs` llevado a las `BBDD`, y trato de ver lo siguiente:

```
//Requerimos el módulo node mysql y lo metemos dentro de la variable 'mysql'
var mysql = require('mysql');

//Nos conectamos a la base de datos 'base_de_pruebas' y lo metemos dentro de la variable 'connection'
//Definimos la conexión mediante el MÉTODO 'createConnection()'
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'base_de_pruebas',
   port: 3306   //El puerto no es obligatorio ponerlo
});

//Imprimimos en consola si hay un error que impida la conexión o por el contrario, nos dirá si la conexión es correcta
connection.connect(function(error){
   if(error){
      console.log('No se ha podido conectar');
   }else{
      console.log('Conexion correcta a la base de datos: '+mysql.database);
   }
});


//Finalmente desconectamos de la base de datos
connection.end();
```

Nos conectamos a la base de datos, hay una conexión correcta, PERO, no consigo que, al poner el `console.log(Conexión correcta a la base de datos: '+mysql.database);` me saque el nombre de la propia base de datos llamada base_de_pruebas

¿Cómo es el comando para poder verlo?

Comment: ¿Has probado con `connection.config.database`? El objeto `mysql` no maneja la conexión, en cambio el objeto `connection` si que lo hace. Prueba y comenta el resultado. Si deseas usar `this`, dado que usas una función explícita, podrías hacerlo con: `this.options.database`. Saludos

Comment: Con connection.config.database funciona correctamente. Había usado connection.database, pero no config. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues vaya, que bien. Igual me equivoqué en el comentario sobre `this`. Debería funcionar también con `this.config.database`. Saludos

Comment: Oh perdón, no probé this. Ahora pruebo y te digo!!
Vale no, con this no me deja hacerlo